# Serverless Cannot resolve variable

Tags: javascript, serverless

I would like to take a param from a result of an external JS function but I retrieve this error:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "resources.Resources.FileBucket.Properties.BucketName": Value not found at "file" source
```

This is my (a piece) serverless file:

```
service: backend-uploader
frameworkVersion: '3'
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-west-1

resources:
  Resources:
    FileBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${file(./unique-bucket-name.cjs):bucketName}
```

This is my file unique-bucket-name.cjs in the same directory:

```
module.export = async function () {
  return { bucketName: 'something' }
}
```

I have tried using `self` and importing the file as `custom`  but the error still.
I have tried to use a Json with the same response and it works.

Why my JS file can't be taken from serverless?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there's no much difference between using a JSON file to store the variables and a cjs. Looks like internally Serverless has some logic to parse the files and fetch the values

[Serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables) points towards using a JSON file:

```
${file(./config.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):CREDS}
```

But, I've also seen some [examples](https://forum.serverless.com/t/unable-to-get-variables-when-files-are-in-different-folders/16390) of people referencing to YML files instead.